# Why can't I allocate an array of a class with deleted or private destructor?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, destructor, private

I recently ran into this problem at work. A library I'm using makes use of reference counted objects and implements its own way of handling it. Part of the implementation is that each class of the library has a private destructor. Im guessing this is to prevent creation of objects on the stack as the library manages objects lifetime automatically (Its a scene graph).

Anyways, I wanted to allocate an array of such a class on the heap and ran into the following problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    class test
    {
    public:
        test() {
            cout << "ctor" << endl;
        }

        //~test() = delete; also doesnt work

    private:
        ~test()
        {
            cout << "dtor" << endl;
        }

    };

    int main()
    {
        //works
        auto oneInstance = new test;

        //doesnt work
        auto manyInstances = new test[3];
    }
```

The array allocation produces the following error using GCC:

```
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:15:5: error: ‘test::~test()’ is private
     ~test()
     ^
source_file.cpp:26:36: error: within this context
     auto manyInstances = new test[3];
                                    ^
```

Why does the destructor need to be public/available in order to allocate an array of this class on the heap? It works fine when only allocating a single instance like in the line before. I also tried using the more modern "delete" syntax, but it produced the same result.

Is there any kind of magic in the new[] operator that I'm not aware of?

EDIT:

Thanks for the quick help. Im wondering why this code doesnt print "dtor" twice though:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
    test() {
        static int allocations = 0;
        ++allocations;

        if(allocations == 3)
        {
            //produce exception
            throw 1;
        }
        cout << "ctor" << endl;
    }

    ~test()
    {
        cout << "dtor" << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    //works
    auto oneInstance = new test;

    //doesnt work
    try {
    auto manyInstances = new test[3];
    }
    catch(...)
    {
            cout << "error?";
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
ctor ctor dtor error?
```

Comment: This would also fail with `auto manyInstances = test()` and work with `auto manyInstances = new (test*)[3];`.

Comment: Regarding your edit, you only successfully construct 2 instances of `test`.  The first is pointed to by `oneInstance` and never deleted, so its destructor is never called.  The second is destroyed by `new[]` after constructing the second element of the array throws.

Comment: But the construction of the second element doesnt fail, does it? Just the third fails. The ctor print is after throw.

Comment: Yes, the third throws.  So if `oneInstance` were ommitted then two would be destroyed.  No destructor call is made for an object who's constructor throws.

Comment: Im dumb, you are correct. Thanks! For some reason I completely forgot about the oneInstance allocation.

Comment: @BaummitAugen not really a duplicate IMO, there is also the question of what `throw;` does in OP's question and in my answer.  Not to mention OP asking for an explanation of his output.  Which in my opinion is a valid question, especially given that he has good sample code

Comment: @Curious The `throw;` is not even in the question atm, and the second part is a dupe anyways.

Comment: @BaummitAugen the question was edited to not be asking that.  Still, the answer has that so should be useful to people.  I can edit the title of the question to include it.  Also even if the `throw 1` and the number of constructions was the question that should be valid?  I feel like if a question combines two already answered questions into one example where someone gets confused because of how both things interact, that still remains a valid question, don't you think?

Comment: @Curious As I said, the other part is just another duplicate, and not even a hard to find one. Of course the question is valid, it's just been asked before and is thus a duplicate.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Ok. You know probably know best. But I feel like this question could be reopened.

Comment: @BaummitAugen that was also a part of the question and one of the reasons i think it should be reopened. They talked about that in the comments above

Comment: @Curious Ah right, thanks.

Comment: @BaummitAugen think it should be reopened then :) ?

Comment: @Curious Nah. *"Im dumb, you are correct. Thanks! For some reason I completely forgot about the oneInstance allocation."* is basically a typo. :) (Fyi, score in reopen queue is 1 leave closed, 1 reopen, so let's see how the community decides.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because of exceptions, the array version of `new[]` has to go and call the destructor on elements that have been previously allocated when an exception propagates to ensure exception safety.  The single element `new` does not need to do that.  If allocation fails, it just fails, no need to destroy anything.

**§ 8.3.4 New [expr.new/20]**

> If the new-expression creates an array of objects of class type, the destructor is potentially invoked

---

Regarding your edit, see the following quote from the C++17 standard

**§ 8.17 Throwing an exception [expr.throw/4]**

> If no exception is presently being handled, evaluating a throw-expression with no operand calls `std::terminate()`

---

Regarding your second edit, you have missed counting an instance of `test` that you created via `new` (not `new[]`), that leads to the first instance of `test` being created, that's where the confusion about number of constructions comes from.

Comment: That's very subtle. Wouldn't have guessed it.

Comment: Thank you, we already suspected something like that. However, I'm wondering why this piece of code doesnt print "dtor" twice: Whoops, cant post code here. See main.

Comment: @StoryTeller I thought an empty `throw;` just calls `std::terminate`?

Comment: Adjusted the code again, however, still confused. See main. :D

Comment: @Mille25 edited with precise quote from standard

Comment: @StoryTeller found it!  It was in `[expr.throw]`

Comment: Surprisingly, they did not add a special case, so marking the constructor as noexcept is not enough to let things compile.